# Can't Pull Docker Image From Google Container Registry on Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, coreos, google-container-registry

I am running CoreOS on a Google Compute Instance. I am trying to start a service to run a custom image I have in my private Google Container Registry.  Based on documentation, I need to run `gcloud docker -- pull <image>`.  When I do that, I get the error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

I have resolved similar issues setting the Docker environment variables using docker-machine.  Unfortunately, that command is not available.

I have checked the ensure the Computer instance has read access to Storage.

How do I get my Docker image from my Google Container Registry to my machine running CoreOS in Goolge Compute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gcloud CLI runs in a container on CoreOS, which has the unfortunate effect of breaking `gcloud docker`.

Please take a look at our [advanced authentication options](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication), e.g. for an image hosted on gcr.io (as opposed to us.gcr.io, eu.gcr.io ...)

`docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io`